# Is this algorithm's Big oh is n^3 rather than n^2

Tags: algorithm, big-o

```
def triangles(A):
  n = len(A)
  result = 0
  for x in xrange(n):
    z=x+2
    for y in xrange(x + 1, n):
      while (z < n and A[x] + A[y] > A[z]):
        z += 1
      result += z - y - 1
  return result
```

This is an example of the solution in the codility (https://codility.com/media/train/13-CaterpillarMethod.pdf)

In the manual, they claim that the big-Oh of this algorithm is O(N^2)

Bout I think big-Oh is O(N^3) as the worst case's iteration will be

(n-1)(n-2) + (n-2)(n-3) + ..... + 1*0

so I think its big-Oh will be O(N^3).

Can anybody explain why the big-Oh of this algorithm is O(N^2)?

or am I right?

Comment: `(n-1)(n-2) + (n-2)(n-3) + ..... + 1*0` can be represented to `a*n^2 + b*n + c` (`a`, `b`, `c` is constant). Not based your code, but you're thinking formula is still `O(n^2)`.

Comment: what i want to mean in (n-1)(n-2) + (n-2)(n-3)+ .... + 1*0 formular is that there are n number of each sum so n * n^2 will happen. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` loop over `z` will, accumulately, only run *once* (`<n` times) for each execution of the `for` loop over `y`, since `z` is reset only in the scope *outside* of the `for` loop over `y`. Hence a rough upper bound loop count of "inner scope" is along the lines `n*(n+n)` (which is in `O(n^2)`) and not `n*n*n`. W.r.t. calculating complexity, we might as well consider the `while` loop over `z` as a loop *parallell* to the `for` loop over `y`, rather than one *nested*  within the `for` loop over `y`.

I.e., same complexity as e.g.:

```
def triangles(A):
  n = len(A)
  result = 0
  for x in xrange(n):
    z=x+2
    while (z < n)
      z += 1
    for y in xrange(x + 1, n):
      ...
  return result
```

Comment: Thank you i taught initializer in the for loop of y

Comment: @TaeWonYoon happy to help. As `z` is declared in the beginning of the scope of the `for` loop over `x`, it is that `z` that "lives" throughout the other loops contained in the scope of the `for` loop over `x` (in fact, no other declaration of `z` can be inferred, even implicitly).

Answer (score 0):

For each value of `x`, `z` can only be increased up to `n` times. Once `z` is equal to `n` then no iterations of the inner loop is possible until `x` is increased again. So `n` values of `x` with `n` iterations of the inner loop gives `n^2`.

Comment: is for-loop made by 'y' doesn't count?

Comment: The y loop runs n times for each value of x, the same as the inner loop. The total complexity of both inner loops together are bounded by `n` though.